# Restricted Aliasing using `restrict` type qualifier and `unique_ptr` in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, smart-pointers, strict-aliasing

To restrict [pointer aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html), I have used so far the `__restrict__` type qualifier as described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html) in the section on C++ extensions provided by the GNU GCC compiler. For instance the following function,

```cpp
void fn (int *__restrict__ rptr, int &__restrict__ rref)
 {
   /* ... */
 }
```

accepts a restricted pointer and a restricted reference as its arguments.

With the introduction of [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) into the C++ standard, I wonder whether the GCC compiler would provide the same optimized (or better) machine code by using `unique_ptr`.

Should one still use such extensions like `__restrict__`? Is there a better way in more recent standards of C++ to produce the same optimization (for pointers and references)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__restrict__` and `unique_ptr` do different things.  `__restrict__` promises that nothing else refers to this object (so the compiler can optimize).  `unique_ptr` manages the lifetime of a heap allocated object.  It won't allow the optimizer to make any assumptions.

It would be nice if there was a way of saying "this `unique_ptr` is the only way of referring to this object", but I don't know if GCC supports that yet.

Comment: But for example, Mark Nelson says, in [Dr. Dobb’s](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708), “So what exactly is the meaning of the word unique in [the context of `unique_ptr`]? ... When you create a unique_ptr object, you are declaring that you are going to have __exactly one copy of this pointer__.” So that is very close to what `__restrict__` does, as far as I understand.

Comment: The article is wrong.  You are declaring that you are going to have exactly one copy *responsible for ownership*.  There is nothing wrong with passing a raw pointer to the owned object provided that the function doesn't try and store the pointer anywhere,